# Triple if statement in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]Just seeing if anybody can help me out. I am getting lost in my written statements:

The formula I am trying to write is in Column AV.

Column G is "Current #" Column AZ is "Optimized #"

Column BB is for Strictly for Removals and can have multiple #'s separated by a comma.

If # in column ba = then replace, if its in BB then remove, If device type = RET then Retain.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([@[Device '#]],OPT_300Carlton[[Replacing '#]:[Device Type '#]],6,FALSE)="RET","Retain Use New#",IF(VLOOKUP([@[Device '#]],OPT_300Carlton[[Replacing '#]:[Device Type '#]],1,FALSE)=[@[Device '#]],"Replace Use New#","Remove Use New"))
```

THis is what I written, but its failing because of too many functions.

Comment: `If # in column ba` <---  which part of the formula refers to column ba? Pls share sample data to test ur formula.. (used `tables` format as in stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: might be a situation where `SWITCH()` may be cleaner...

Comment: perhaps failure is being caused by `VLOOKUP` returning #N/A?

Comment: Try to provide the OPT_300Carlton[[Replacing '#]:[Device Type '#]] Range sample here. Did the first column is = [@[Device '#]]?

Comment: The intention of this middle bit would be clearer if rewritten using a MATCH: "IF(VLOOKUP([@[Device '#]],OPT_300Carlton[[Replacing '#]:[Device Type '#]],1,FALSE)=[@[Device '#]]" could be simpler as IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@[Device '#]],OPT_300Carlton[[Replacing '#]],0)) - rather than "does this thing match the cell at the row where the things is found, this is more directly "is this thing found in the list". Alternative could to use IF(COUNTIF(OPT_300Carlton[[Replacing '#]],[@[Device '#]])>0 which I think I prefer perhaps.

Comment: My apologies i thought I uploaded a screen shot. I hope this clears up my example.

Answer (score 0):

I donno how to use table formula. here it is (my version)

```
=IF(BF2="RET","Retain Use New#",
    IF(ISNUMBER(BB2),"Replace Use New#",
        IF(ISNUMBER(BA2),"Remove Use New","")
        )
    )
```

and drag downwards.

Idea : check for "RET" 1st, then chk number on BB2, then only chk number on BA2.

Please share if it works/not.